# Showing the equality with $\sum_{p \leq x} \log \left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right)$.

Tags: number-theory

> Show that $$\sum_{p \leq x} \log \left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right) = -\log \log x - B + O\left (\frac{1}{\log x} \right)$$ and deduce $$\prod_{p\leq x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p} \right) = 
> \frac{e^{-B}}{\log x} + O\left( \frac{1}{\log ^2 x } \right)$$

So far I have not had luck in showing either equality. I have proved the following:  $$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log x + O(1),$$
$$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log x + C + O\left( \frac{1}{\log x} \right).$$ With these two, I am not sure how to combine them to obtain $\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right)$, rather than $\frac{( \log p) - 1}{p}$. Any ideas on how to proceed/conclude with both equalities?

Comment: See theorem 3.4: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = -\frac{1}{p}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\sum_{p \leq x}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = -\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}+\sum_{p\leq x}\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = -\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p} + \text{const}.
\end{align}
Now, use what you have proved.